# Folding/Unfolding table with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which is pretty big, so I need a way to unfold it  all the time, and unfold it only necessary.

How can I do that with HTML? Do I need Javascript for this? If so, what's the code for this?

Comment: Can you give some sort of example? Im not too sure what you mean by folding/unfolding a table

Comment: Why don't you add paging instead of folding / unfolding? That way you could keep the data cached and display only the current page. Then you wouldn't have to worry about poor performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will use jquery you can check the code below.

In css:

```
.collapsed-table tr {
  display: none;
}
```

In html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<table class="collapsed-table">
   <caption>Expand/collapce</caption> 
   <tr>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
   ....
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.collapsed-table > caption').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('collapsed-table');
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the header (thead) visible at all times and toggle the visibility of the body (tbody) when the user clicks on the folding button.

Using jQuery:

```
$('#foldbutton').click(function()
{
$('tbody').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but others can have the same problem and no one have provided a complete solution, so if you want to fold / unfold something with an animation, I developed a script named [TextShower](https://github.com/filsmick/TextShower) that allows you to do that. It's highly customizable and you can edit its source freely. Hope this helps :)